# How to access web_sys::CustomEvent.detail data from rust

Tags: wasm-bindgen

Have code which generates an https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.CustomEvent.html.

Logging `event.detail()` results in: `{index: 1}`. This is of type `JsValue`, but how to obtain the integer 1 value in rust?

One way could be
https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/iterating-over-js-values.html
Other betters ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js_sys::Reflect` seems to fit for this:
https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/Reflect/fn.get.html

```
let js_index = js_sys::Reflect::get(&event.detail(), &JsValue::from_str("index")).unwrap();    
let i : usize = js_index.as_f64().unwrap() as usize;
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas your answer helped me find a solution to [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203156)